# Leaflet choropleth plot not plotting as expected -

Tags: r, leaflet

I have some geographical data that I would like to plot in a `leaflet` plot.

```
# A tibble: 52 × 2
   provincia     mean_price
   <chr>              <dbl>
 1 A Coruña         179833.
 2 Albacete         148584.
 3 Alicante         418148.
 4 Almería          142338.
```

I can get the geographic coordinates from the `mapSpain` package.

```
library(mapSpain)
provincias = mapSpain::esp_get_prov() %>%
  select(c("cpro", "ine.prov.name", "iso2.prov.name.es", "iso2.prov.name.ca", "iso2.prov.name.ga", "iso2.prov.name.eu"))
```

This contains a few columns for the names of the regions plus the geographical coordinates.

I want to join my `mean_price` up with the geographical data - (since the data is not able to 100% match/join I loop over the columns to find the region which "fits". I run the following to join the two data sets up:

```
main_df <- map(names(provincias)[-1],
           ~ regex_left_join(df, provincias, by = c("provincia" = .x))) %>%
  reduce(power_left_join, by = c("provincia", "mean_price"),
         conflict = coalesce_xy)
```

This gets me my "main" dataframe which looks like:

```
   provincia     mean_price cpro  ine.prov.name    iso2.prov.name.es iso2.prov.name.ca iso2.pr…¹ iso2.…²                  geometry
   <chr>              <dbl> <chr> <chr>            <chr>             <chr>             <chr>     <chr>              <GEOMETRY [°]>
 1 A Coruña         179833. 15    Coruña, A        La Coruña         NA                A Coruña  NA       GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
 2 Albacete         148584. 02    Albacete         Albacete          NA                NA        NA      POLYGON ((-0.928884 38.7…
 3 Alicante         418148. 03    Alicante/Alacant Alicante          Alacant           NA        NA       GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
 4 Almería          142338. 04    Almería          Almería           NA                NA        NA      MULTIPOLYGON (((-1.63003…
 5 Araba - Álava    243705. 01    Araba/Álava      Álava             NA                NA        Araba    GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
 6 Asturias         149180. 33    Asturias         Asturias          NA                NA        NA      MULTIPOLYGON (((-4.51230…
 7 Badajoz          147803. 06    Badajoz          Badajoz           NA                NA        NA      POLYGON ((-5.046996 38.7…
 8 Barcelona        462814. 08    Barcelona        Barcelona         NA                NA        NA      MULTIPOLYGON (((2.778513…
 9 Bizkaia          286462. 48    Bizkaia          NA                NA                NA        Bizkaia MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.41284…
10 Burgos           134636. 09    Burgos           Burgos            NA                NA        NA      MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.14139…
```

Now, I have my variable of interest `mean_price` matched with the geographical coordinates. I now want to plot a `leaflet` map but I am having difficultly.

I run the folllowing code:

```
main_df = main_df %>% 
  mutate(
    bins = ntile(mean_price, 52) # I cretae bins for the choropleth colour pallet
  ) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf()

pal = colorBin("RdYlBu", domain = main_df$mean_price, bins = main_df$bins)
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  setView(lng = 2.154007, lat =  41.390205, zoom = 12) %>%
  addPolygons(data = main_df,
              color = "darkblue",
              weight = 1,
              smoothFactor = 0.5,
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              fillColor = pal(main_df$mean_price),
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 5,
                color = "grey",
                dashArray = "", # keep straightlines
                fillOpacity = 0.7,
                bringToFront = TRUE
              )
  )
```

> Error in to_ring.default(x) :    Don't know how to get polygon data
> from object of class XY,GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,sfg In addition: Warning
> messages: 1: In pal(main_df$mean_price) :   Some values were outside
> the color scale and will be treated as NA 2: sf layer has inconsistent
> datum (+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs).
> Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'

Question: How can I correctly plot the cloropleth plot in leaflet? and how can I adjust it to have say 10 bins?

When I adjust it to 10 bins I get this error:

> Error in cut.default(x, binsToUse, labels = FALSE, include.lowest =
> TRUE,  :    'breaks' are not unique

Libraries:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(htmltools)
library(mapview)
library(htmlwidgets)

library(powerjoin)
library(purrr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
```

Data:

```
df = structure(list(provincia = c("A Coruña", "Albacete", "Alicante", 
"Almería", "Araba - Álava", "Asturias", "Badajoz", "Barcelona", 
"Bizkaia", "Burgos", "Cantabria", "Castellón", "Ceuta", "Ciudad Real", 
"Cuenca", "Cáceres", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Gipuzkoa", "Girona", 
"Granada", "Guadalajara", "Huelva", "Huesca", "Illes Balears", 
"Jaén", "La Rioja", "Las Palmas", "León", "Lleida", "Lugo", 
"Madrid", "Melilla", "Murcia", "Málaga", "Navarra", "Ourense", 
"Palencia", "Pontevedra", "Salamanca", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", 
"Segovia", "Sevilla", "Soria", "Tarragona", "Teruel", "Toledo", 
"Valencia", "Valladolid", "Zamora", "Zaragoza", "Ávila"), mean_price = c(179833.167862839, 
148583.87109077, 418148.151437643, 142337.792926704, 243704.750636132, 
149179.732438607, 147802.894486692, 462813.775190776, 286461.604484305, 
134635.540239044, 201214.437926878, 139819.15323646, 204318.181818182, 
113856.401715511, 116992.998609179, 143137.441025641, 251270.65520481, 
166586.746650426, 340663.440746753, 365733.360551724, 219325.194605466, 
173221.569037657, 142430.992912371, 141754.603535354, 749037.540922619, 
131396.292428198, 160838.235963581, 656553.777123633, 140312.919506463, 
160485.155614973, 129787.667711599, 433665.652781242, 234306.12244898, 
188635.237652749, 687127.622056842, 197388.050991501, 137829.640394089, 
123450.853813559, 230344.604904632, 159999.046077894, 328912.419004007, 
184829.536144578, 180692.511036468, 155759.235955056, 193651.956693536, 
128909.006756757, 132623.629553967, 177825.529404212, 165240.297002725, 
116820.125531915, 164934.932635983, 124977.724215247)), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

```
provincias <- sf::st_transform(provincias, crs = 4326)

n_colors <- 52
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n_colors, "RdYlBu"))

pal = colorBin(my_palette(n_colors), domain = spain_summary$mean_price, bins = spain_summary$bins, na.color = "transparent", alpha = 1)
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = provincias,
              weight = 1,
              smoothFactor = 0.5,
              color = "white",
              fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~pal(spain_summary$mean_price),
              stroke = TRUE,
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                color = "black",
                weight = 2,
                #dashArray = "",
                fillOpacity = 0.8,
                bringToFront = TRUE
                )
  )
```

Comment: try with `filleColor = ~pal(mean_price)` in the addPolygons

Comment: Thanks, looks like there were some problems with my data also. I updated my answer to show what I have done - it seems to work now...